Diesel failing to connect to Postgres because too many clients
I'm attempting to write a Rocket endpoint in Rust that connects to a Postgres database, but the application fails just after it's launched. It seems to be a connection pool issue and I've checked all of the usual suspects, like the Postgres configuration, which currently allows a maximum of 100 connections and the connection pool limit in Rocket.toml, which I've bumped around from 1 to 75 for testing purposes and it still fails. I've also successfully verified that I'm able to connect to the database server from other applications, including the command line using psql. No other applications are connecting to the database server.
Rocket.toml:
[default.databases.diesel] # Delete this after testing
url = "postgres://postgres:password@localhost:5432/diesel"
pool = { max_size = 10 }

Rocket
use crate::schema::files;
use diesel::prelude::*;
use diesel::RunQueryDsl;
use rocket::fairing::AdHoc;
use rocket::response::{status::Created, Debug};
use rocket::serde::json::Json;
use rocket_sync_db_pools::database;
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use uuid::Uuid;

#[database("diesel")]
struct Db(diesel::PgConnection);

type Result<T, E = Debug<diesel::result::Error>> = std::result::Result<T, E>;

#[derive(Clone, Debug, Default, Deserialize, Eq, Hash, Ord, PartialEq, PartialOrd, Serialize, Insertable)]
#[diesel(table_name = files)]
pub struct File {
    pub file_id: Uuid,
    pub file_path: String,
}

#[post("/", data = "<file>")]
async fn create(db: Db, mut file: Json<File>) -> Result<Created<Json<File>>> {
    let post_value = file.clone();
    let id = db
        .run(move |conn| {
            diesel::insert_into(files::table)
                .values(&*post_value)
                .returning(files::file_id)
                .get_result::<Uuid>(conn)
        })
        .await?;

    file.file_id = id;

    Ok(Created::new("/").body(file))
}

pub fn stage() -> AdHoc {
    AdHoc::on_ignite("File Stage", |rocket| async {
        rocket.attach(Db::fairing()).mount("/files", routes![create])
    })
}

Relevant Startup Code
#[macro_use]
extern crate rocket;

#[launch]
fn rocket() -> _ {
    rocket::build()
        .mount("/", routes![index])
        .attach(resources::file_resource::stage())
}

Error
timed out waiting for connection: connection to server at
"localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: FATAL: sorry,
too many clients already

   0: rust_begin_unwind
             at /rustc/07dca489ac2d933c78d3c5158e3f43beefeb02ce/library/std/src/panicking.rs:645:5
   1: core::panicking::panic_fmt
             at /rustc/07dca489ac2d933c78d3c5158e3f43beefeb02ce/library/core/src/panicking.rs:72:14
   2: core::panicking::panic_display
             at /rustc/07dca489ac2d933c78d3c5158e3f43beefeb02ce/library/core/src/panicking.rs:196:5
   3: <rocket::error::Error as core::ops::drop::Drop>::drop::panic_cold_display
             at /rustc/07dca489ac2d933c78d3c5158e3f43beefeb02ce/library/core/src/panic.rs:99:13
   4: <rocket::error::Error as core::ops::drop::Drop>::drop
             at /home/senfo/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/rocket-0.5.0/src/error.rs:279:9
   5: core::ptr::drop_in_place<rocket::error::Error>
             at /rustc/07dca489ac2d933c78d3c5158e3f43beefeb02ce/library/core/src/ptr/mod.rs:507:1
   6: core::ptr::drop_in_place<core::result::Result<rocket::rocket::Rocket<rocket::phase::Ignite>,rocket::error::Error>>
             at /rustc/07dca489ac2d933c78d3c5158e3f43beefeb02ce/library/core/src/ptr/mod.rs:507:1
   7: osim::main
             at ./src/main.rs:20:1
   8: core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once
             at /rustc/07dca489ac2d933c78d3c5158e3f43beefeb02ce/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:250:5

It seems to be failing somewhere after the stage is attached in the main startup code. I haven't been able to find any additional configuration settings I might be overlooking. Does anybody see anything obvious? I used the Rocket database examples on GitHub as a reference. None of their examples specifically connect to Postgres, so I had to make some assumptions.

This error is emitted by your database server as you seem to request more database connection than what is configured there. See the postgresql documentation for details for the relevant setting.
Usually you want to use something like 10 connections in your connection pool. 75 is already a really large number.

Thank you for the response. I apologize for the ambiguity in my original post. I agree 75 is really large. I verified Postgres is configured for 100 max connections. I've tried reducing the thread pool size anywhere from 1 to 75. For sake of completeness, I did just reduce the thread pool back down to 10 and it still produces the same error message, unfortunately. There are no other active connections to the database server, so it seems like I must be doing something wrong in my code, but I'm still struggling to determine what it is.

I checked the active connections as the app was launching and I noticed it spike to 108. I bumped the configuration up to allow for 500 maximum connections (probably overkill) and it seems to be working now.

That sounds strange for me. It might be worth to fill a issue about that in the rocket repository if you can provide a complete minimal example.

I agree with you. I'm voting to close my own question because I think this potentially represents a bug in the framework (not accusing; just hypothesizing). I'm not going to mark this as having been answered because (and I think you'd agree) it seems the problem might be elsewhere. Regardless, I do want you to know I appreciate your response and for helping me to troubleshoot the issue.
